# Conflict between NewDocumentEnvironment and enumerate

Tags: environments, enumerate, xparse

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{probctr}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{prob}{o}
 {%
  \par
  \addvspace{.15in}%
  \addtocounter{probctr}{1}%
  \noindent\textbf{Problem \theprobctr}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{ (#1 points)}%
  \par\nopagebreak\smallskip\noindent\ignorespaces%
 }
 {\addvspace{.15in}}

 \begin{document}
     \begin{prob}[15]
       \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
       \item Item 1
       \item Item 2
     \end{enumerate}

      Consider this ...
   \end{prob}

 \end{document}
```

If I comment out the line "Consider this ...", the document compiles fine. But with that line I get `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: You need `\par\addvspace{.15in}` in the “end” part.

Comment: passerby51: I suggest to use `\refstepcounter{prbcounter}` instead of `\addtocounter`. You  can use labels then

Comment: @egreg, I see. So the there reason this has never happened before is probably the blank line I always had before `\end{prob}`. The error is very misleading though.

Comment: @passerby51: Yes, it's an implicit `\par`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks. What is the advantage though besides saving an extra {1}?

Comment: @passerby51: Extra `{1}`? Sorry, I am confused!

Comment: @passerby51 Yes, it is a bit confusing; but since `\addvspace` constantly appears at the end of lists, the LaTeX team has decided to issue `\@noitemerr` when `\addvspace` is in unproper place.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I meant the advantage seems to be that you don't need to specify by how much to increment the counter; `refstepcounter` increments by 1 by default (it seems). Otherwise, what is the advantage of using it over `\addtocounter`?

Comment: @egreg, thanks... I guess something like "Error: `\addvspace` used in horizontal mode" would have been much more suitable. I have no idea how feasible that would have been.

Comment: @passerby51 Possibly so; alas, the team decided otherwise.

Comment: @passerby51: Using `\refstepcounter` allows to use a label for your problem environment, say `\begin{prob}  \label{foo}` .... and later on, you could say `In Problem \ref{foo}` ... for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, Oh... I see, that seals the deal then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As egreg noted in the comments:

The `\addvspace` macro must be issued in vertical mode!

There is no conflict between `\NewDocumentCommand` and `enumerate` etc or `enumitem`. The solution to the error is that `\addvspace` must follow an explicit `\par`. The error would occur for `\newenvironment` too (see the `probtrad` environment).

I suggest to use `\refstepcounter{probctr}` instead of `\addtocounter`. The former allows to use `\label` and refer to it.

Please note, that my initial version worked (using `\vskip 0.15in` instead of `\par\addvspace{0.15in}`) just because `\vskip` implies `\par`). It was not really correct then. Joe Cocker sang: `With a little help from my friends` I took the comment (by permission from `egreg`) to apply it here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % as an alternative to enumerate
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{probctr}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{prob}{o}
{%
  \par
  \addvspace{.15in}%
  \refstepcounter{probctr}%
  \noindent\textbf{Problem \theprobctr}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{ (#1 points)}%
  \par\nopagebreak\smallskip\noindent\ignorespaces%
}{%
  \par\addvspace{.15in}% egreg's suggestion
}



\newenvironment{probtrad}[1][]{%
 \par
 \addvspace{.15in}%
  \refstepcounter{probctr}%
  \noindent\textbf{Problem \theprobctr}%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{ (#1 points)}%
  \par\nopagebreak\smallskip\noindent\ignorespaces%
}{%
  \par\addvspace{.15in}% egreg's suggestion
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{prob}[15]
   \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
   \end{enumerate}
   Consider this ...
 \end{prob}

 \begin{probtrad}[20]
   \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
   \item Item 3
   \item Item 4
   \end{enumerate}
   Now consider this ...
 \end{probtrad}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with using `\vskip 0.15in` instead?