# How to fix interference between NewDocumentEnvironment and enumitem package

Tags: environments, enumitem, xparse, comma-separated-list

I'm trying to write a couple of new environments and commands to save short answers from a list with enumerate environment, the idea being to save the first and second level using references to lists stored in memory.

I am using the `enumitem`, `multicol`, `pgffor`, `tcolorbox` and `xparse` packages.

I explained, I created two new environments each with a defined command inside them to be able to save the short answers and I added a pair of keys to enumitem.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{saveanswer} whit \answi
\NewDocumentEnvironment{saveansweri} whit \answii
\SetEnumitemKey{columns}{before=\begin{multicols}{#1},after=\end{multicols}}%
\SetEnumitemKey{savekey}{before=\begin{saveanswer}{#1},after=\end{saveanswer}}%
\SetEnumitemKey{ansref}{before=\begin{saveansweri}{#1},after=\end{saveansweri}}%
```

Here begins my dilemma. If I use the enumitem keys, it loses the alignment of the lists in the last element and affects all enumerate environments (with or without the enabled key)
[image: using key from enumitem]

If I comment the enumitem keys and encapsulate the enumerate environments within "saveanswer" the ones I have created partially solve the issue, but it still affects the other enumerate environments.
[image: enumerate in saveanswer]

With both cases it fails, in addition, I can not run the foreach loop to keep the items correctly in the list. I would like it to look like this:
[image: IDEAL]

I'm a little lost in this, i read [Conflict between NewDocumentEnvironment and enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248832/7832) and maybe the way to get what I'm looking for is not the right one and it should be done differently.
Regards:
The MWE:

```
% !file: forum.tex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { files:[forum.aux, forum.log] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Set key for multicols in enumitem
\SetEnumitemKey{columns}{before=\begin{multicols}{#1},after=\end{multicols}}%
\SetEnumitemKey{savekey}{before=\begin{saveanswer}{#1},after=\end{saveanswer}}%
\SetEnumitemKey{ansref}{before=\begin{saveansweri}{#1},after=\end{saveansweri}}%

% Some definition
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364763/7832
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Reporter macro, is expandable
\cs_new:Npn \reportnumberofseqitems #1{%
 \seq_count:c {l_bcp_data_#1_seq}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\storedata}{mm}
  {
   \bcp_store_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\appenddata}{+m+m}
 {
  \bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdata}{O{1}m}
 {
  \bcp_get_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bcp_store_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist or clear it if it exists
  \seq_if_exist:cTF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
   { \seq_gclear:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
  % append the items
  \__bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bcp_append_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist, do nothing if it exists
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
  % append the items
  \__bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__bcp_append_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % append items one at a time
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:cn { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bcp_get_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % retrieve the requested item
  \seq_item:cn { l_bcp_data_#2_seq } { #1 }
 }
% Save answer in first level answi 
\NewDocumentEnvironment{saveanswer}{m}{%
\NewDocumentCommand\answi{m}{%,
    \appenddata{#1}{{##1}}%
    }% close \answi
}{%
}% close saveanswer

% Save answer in second level answii 
\newcounter{myNo}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{saveansweri}{m}{%
\stepcounter{myNo}
\NewDocumentCommand\answii{m}{%,
    \appenddata{#1:\themyNo}{{##1}}%
    }% close \answii
}{%
\appenddata{#1}{{\begin{enumerate}\space%
\foreach \x in {1,...,\reportnumberofseqitems{#1:\themyNo}}{%
    \item \space \getdata[\x]{#1:\themyNo} \space%
                } % close foreach
    \space \end{enumerate}}} % close appendata
}% close saveansweri

\ExplSyntaxOff

% [#1] : pass to tcolorbox
% {#2} : title
% {#3} : list ref
% [#4] : columns
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\showans}{O{} m m O{4}}
{ colback=white,size=small,top=0mm,bottom=1.5mm, left=0mm,width=\columnwidth,title filled,%
  fontupper=\small,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,%
    adjusted title={#2},center title,#1}
  {% 
  \begin{enumerate}[columns=#4,leftmargin=15pt,labelsep=3pt,font=\footnotesize,nosep,widest=25,]%
  \small
  \setlength{\columnsep}{0pt} 
   \foreach \x in {1,...,\reportnumberofseqitems{#3}} {
    \item \getdata[\x]{#3}%
    }
  \end{enumerate}
  }%
\begin{document}

\section{It looks like this}
\subsection{Exercices}
\begin{enumerate}[savekey=test1]
\setenumerate{labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=1cm, itemsep=0pt,widest=80}%
\item True False
      \begin{enumerate}[ansref=test1] 
      \item $2\alpha+2\delta=90^{\circ}$ \answii{True}
      \item $\angle EDF=45^{\circ}$ \answii{False}
      \end{enumerate} 
\item Factor $x^{2}-2x+1$  \answi{$\left(x-1\right)^{2}$} 
\item Factor$3x+3y+3z$    \answi{$3(x+y+z)$}
\item True False
      \begin{enumerate}[ansref=test1]
      \item $2\alpha+2\delta=90^{\circ}$ \answii{False}
      \item $\alpha=\delta$ \answii{True}
      \item $\alpha=\delta$ \answii{True}
      \end{enumerate} 
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{answers}
\showans{Exercices 1}{test1}[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks very complex. And `\setenumerate` is deprecated. You should use `\setlist[enumerate,1]` , i.e. setting the keys for the individual `enumerate` levels here, which is most likely the cause for your problem -- they are mixed

Comment: In my opinion, the issue is the usage of `\themyNo` -- it is not expanded and therefore the lists are mixed

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks for the comment, it is quite complicated, try for several hours looking at the forum something that could adapt, I can not think of another way to address what I want. For the lists maybe I do not need a counter, only to run temporarily, maybe use `\edef\tmp` in `\answii`?

Comment: No, I don't think that something like `\edef\tmp` would be sufficient (and not possible there because of the assignments with `\seq_gput_right:Nnn`, most likely)

Comment: In your `\keych` macro change try to change `\seq_gput_right:cn { l_bcp_data_ \retrievecurrentid _seq }{\item \Alph{enumii}}` to `\seq_gput_right:cx { l_bcp_data_ \retrievecurrentid _seq }{\protect\item \Alph{enumii}}`

Comment: The change you propose does not work, is left with the last value of enumii, will it be an expansion of  \Alph{enumii} problem?

Comment: Well, your fragment is not really useful to me at the moment. Can you send me your current code? You can use the contact form on my personal page (link on my TeX.SE profile page)

Comment: @ChristianHuper: Send mail whit file now.

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as possible...

Comment: Send a reply mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am applying a different strategy, by automatic stepping down and up of `enumerate` levels and storing the `\begin{enumerate}` and `\end{enumerate}` into one **single** list, retrieving the current list id with global `\prop` variable.

```
% !file: forum.tex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { files:[forum.aux, forum.log] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Set key for multicols in enumitem
\SetEnumitemKey{columns}{before=\begin{multicols}{#1},after=\end{multicols}}%
\SetEnumitemKey{savekey}{before={\storecurrentid{#1}\begin{saveanswer}{#1}},after=\end{saveanswer}}%

% Some definition
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364763/7832
\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_bpc_admin_prop 

\cs_new:Npn \storecurrentid #1{%
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_bpc_admin_prop {current-id} {#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \retrievecurrentid {%
  \prop_item:Nn \g_bpc_admin_prop {current-id} 
}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{saveanswer}{m}{%
  \setlist[enumerate,1]{labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=1cm, itemsep=0pt,widest=80}%
  \setlist[enumerate,2]{before={\stepdownlevel},after={\stepuplevel},labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=0.6cm, itemsep=0pt,widest=80}
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }{%
    \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
  }
  \leavevmode
}{%
%
}% close saveanswer

\NewDocumentCommand{\answeris}{+m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:cn { l_bcp_data_ \retrievecurrentid _seq }{\item  #1}
  \par
}

\newcommand{\stepdownlevel}{%
  % Must start a new item with \begin{enumerate} on answer ... 
  \seq_gput_right:cn {l_bcp_data_ \retrievecurrentid _seq} {\item \begin{enumerate}}
  }

\newcommand{\stepuplevel}{%
  % Close current enumerate level
  \seq_gput_right:cn {l_bcp_data_ \retrievecurrentid _seq} {\end{enumerate}}
}

\cs_new:Npn \displayseqcontent #1#2 {%
  \seq_if_empty:cF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } {%
    \seq_log:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{before={},after={},labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=0.6cm, itemsep=0pt,widest=80}
    \begin{enumerate}[#2]
      \small
      \setlength{\columnsep}{0pt} 
      \seq_map_inline:cn { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } {%
        ##1%
      }
    \end{enumerate}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% [#1] : pass to tcolorbox
% {#2} : title
% {#3} : list ref
% [#4] : columns
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\showans}{O{} m m O{4}}
{ colback=white,size=small,top=0mm,bottom=1.5mm, left=0mm,width=\columnwidth,title filled,%
  fontupper=\small,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,%
  adjusted title={#2},center title,#1}
{% 
  \displayseqcontent{#3}{columns=#4,leftmargin=15pt,labelsep=3pt,font=\footnotesize,nosep,widest=25}
}%


% Set the list properties for level 1 and 2
%\setlist[enumerate,1]{labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=1cm, itemsep=0pt,widest=80}%
%\setlist[enumerate,2]{before={\stepdownlevel},after={\typeout{stepping up for \retrievecurrentid}\stepuplevel},labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=0.6cm, itemsep=0pt,widest=80}%

\begin{document}
\section{It looks like this}
\subsection{Exercices}
\begin{enumerate}[savekey=test1]
\item True False
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $2\alpha+2\delta=90^{\circ}$ \answeris{True}
  \item $\angle EDF=45^{\circ}$ \answeris{False}
  \end{enumerate} 
\item Factor $x^{2}-2x+1$  \answeris{$\left(x-1\right)^{2}$} 
\item Factor $3x+3y+3z$    \answeris{$3(x+y+z)$}
\item True False
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $2\alpha+2\delta=90^{\circ}$ \answeris{False}
  \item $\alpha=\delta$ \answeris{True}
  \item $\alpha > \delta$ \answeris{False}
  \item \LaTeX2e\ is cool? \answeris{Very True!}
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[savekey=test2]
\item True False 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $2\alpha+2\delta=90^{\circ}$ \answeris{False}
  \item $\alpha=\delta$ \answeris{True}
  \item $\alpha > \delta$ \answeris{False}
  \item \LaTeX2e\ is cool? \answeris{Very True!}
  \end{enumerate} 

\item True False 

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $2\alpha+2\delta=90^{\circ}$ \answeris{True}
  \item $\angle EDF=45^{\circ}$ \answeris{False}
  \end{enumerate} 

\item Factor $x^{2}-2x+1$  \answeris{$\left(x-1\right)^{2}$} 

\item Factor $3x+3y+3z$    \answeris{$3(x+y+z)$}
\end{enumerate}


\subsection{answers}

\showans[colback=yellow!30!white]{Exercices 1}{test1}[2]

\showans[colback=yellow!30!white]{Exercices 2}{test2}[2]


\showans[colback=yellow!70!blue]{Exercices 1 again}{test1}[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't guarantee this will work always

Comment: Great, it's what I want, now I write from my cell phone, coming home I check it ... thank you very much

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL: I've updated in the meantime.

Comment: @ChristianHuper: Thank you very much for the time you have taken, it is just what I was looking for (with this I save a million hours of work).
Now i know that `\leavmode` solves the interference with enumitem 
A query related to the same subject. With same strategy I want to save the "multiple choice" test keys, 
i have created an environment called "savechoice", a enumitem key "savecch" and command `\keych`, (copy of `\answeris`) whit optional argument, by deault `\item \Alph{enumi}` and `\item # 1` with optional, how can expand the `\Alph{enumi}` of the second enumerate level?...Saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL: Do you mean something like `\setenumerate[enumerate]{label={\Alph*}} and `\setenumerate[enumerate,2]{label*={\arabic*}}? The `label*` means that the parent level (i.e. enumi) will be prepended

Comment: @ChristianHuper: I apologize for my bad english, the space was too short to explain the idea, I edited my question temporarily to clarify the idea (see TMP edit at end of question).